# Performing adding/subtracting in Access table with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm populating a TempTable in Access using data from the queries. I have populated 3 columns (Add, Delete, Buy) so far and I'm trying to find the total of the three of them. Thing is, a lot of don't have values, and some of them are negative values. How would I go about addnig them? I have data in rs2("Add"), rs2("Delete"), and rs2("Buy"). So all ADD values (if there are any are positive), all DELETE are negative (if any) and all BUY are positive.

I'd like to go in a loop possibly...

I took the count of records as intRsCount = 25

```
With rs2
    While Not .EOF
        lngCompanyID = rs2("CompanyID")
        lngUnitPrice = rs2("UnitPrice")
         strSQL2 = "SELECT AddQty from qryAddx WHERE InvValue = " & lngUnitPrice & "  And CompanyId = " & lngCompanyId
        strSQL3 = "SELECT DeleteQty from qryUsedx where UnitValue=" & lngUnitPrice & "  And CompanyId = " & lngCompanyId
        strSQL4 = "SELECT BuyQty from qryVoidx where InvValue =" & lngUnitPrice & "  And CompanyId = " & lngCompanyId

        Set rs3 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL2)
        Set rs4 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL3)
        Set rs5 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL4)
            If rs3.recordCount > 0 Then
              rs2.Edit
              rs2("Added") = rs3("Addqty")
              rs2.Update
            End If
            If rs4.recordCount > 0 Then
                rs2.Edit
                rs2("Delete") = rs4("DelQty")
                rs2.Update
            End If
            If rs5.recordCount > 0 Then
                rs2.Edit
                rs2("Buy") = rs5("BuyQty")
                rs2.Update
            End If
        rs2.MoveNext
        Set rs3 = Nothing
        Set rs4 = Nothing
        Set rs5 = Nothing
    Wend
End With
```

This is my code. I'm trying to add the SUM of ADDED, DELETED and BUY and place it in rs2("Subtotal") and doing this for all 25 rows. I'm not really familiar with ACCESS and how it deals with NULL values, and negative values  (all DELETE values are negative). Thanks.

Comment: Surely you've tried more than this?  Can you share more what has worked?  This would fill out the available info more fully.  (For example, you working for a sum for all 25 records, each record individually?)

Comment: I'm looking for sum of the three columns. So i have 25 rows and three columns. I'm trying to go through the three columns and find a sum of ADD, DELETE and BUY for all 25 rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim strCriteria as String

With rs2
While Not .EOF

    strCriteria = "InvValue = " & !UnitPrice & " And CompanyId = " & !CompanyID

    .Edit
    !Added = Nz(DSum("Addqty", "qryAddx", strCriteria), 0)
    !Delete = Nz(DSum("DeleteQty", "qryUsedx", strCriteria), 0)
    !Buy = Nz(DSum("BuyQty", "qryVoidx", strCriteria), 0)
    .Update

Wend
End With
```

- `DSum()` is inefficient.  If you are running many operations, it may be slow, but otherwise it is fine.
- `Nz()` converts a Null value to zero.

Answer (score 0):

If rs2 is a recordset, you would refer to the columns like this: `rs2.fields("Add").Value`

Do loop through the rows, go with

```
if rs2.recordcount > 0 then
    rs2.movefirst
    while not rs2.eof
        'put your commands here
    wend
end if
```

Comment: This is prolly part of the solution.  The other part would seem to be an integer variable for your record-total, and better handling of Nulls.  It's a bit hard to say, the question is vague.